# Can't run default shell

Tags: macos, unix, shell, root

What to do if I uninstalled my `default shell` (`/opt/local/bin/bash`)? I can't open terminal under my account unless my `default shell` is valid or at least exists. Are there any elegant ways to fix it? This happens sometimes to me.

**Experienced situations:**

Restoring back up.

Mistyping `port uninstall inactive` instead of `port uninstall installed`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are only a couple of ways to do it.

**First one**:

- Open Terminal preferences.
- In General tab, change *Shells open with* and select *Command (complete path)*.
- Fill it with `/bin/bash`, `/bin/zsh` or whatever shell you want.

**Second one**:

On the terminal type the following:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Or the shell you want.

Comment: The second doesn't work because when terminals opens it launches default shell, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I suppose it, but I wanted to let you know.

Comment: w/e, I tested the first one and it both works properly and doesn't involve creating users or rebooting in command line mode. That's the goal.